# Android app theme textViewStyle doesn't work on phone

Tags: android, xml, textview, styles, android-theme

I have so specific problem. I'm applying theme for all textviews. It appears on preview but when I run this app on phone I face with unstyled textview. The styles I set for other views are working. only textviewstyle is not working.

In this sample textview color is green in preview but when i run it on phone its black. Why?

style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/myTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myEditTextStyle</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="myTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="edit text" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"textViewStyle" is not defined in v22.1.1. You can find more detail from the link:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170476